# play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]]

Tags: scala, playframework, timeout

I'm getting the following errors trying to run an existing project that uses Play 2.1.0.  Any ideas?

> [error] application [/] -
>
> ! @6jfa870fl - Internal server error, for (GET) [/web/login] ->
>
> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[TimeoutException:
>   Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]]     at
>   play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:142)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]    at
>   play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]   at
>   play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]    at
>   play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]    at
>   scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
>   [scala-library.jar:na] Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000
>   milliseconds]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:96)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:58)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.Await$.ready(package.scala:86)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]

Answer (score 0):

Best guess : there  is a database call or a webservice call related to login which fails.

If you coud provide the code for the controller which handles (GET) [/web/login] I might be able to give you more  help

Answer (score 0):

Bah, turns out the app wasn't connecting to an API server.  Bad error output :/